# object behavior is different when called from module

Tags: powershell

I am getting some weird behavior from a function (Invoke-EXOScommand) in a module I've written (https://github.com/joxz/PSEXOS). The module is designed to connect to my network switches via JSONRPC.

The error and working scenarios are both in the gist with the json: https://gist.github.com/joxz/195d6ec6d211f6e00421cf13436411fd

So far so good, I'm getting a JSON as a response and convert it with ConvertFrom-Json to Powershell objects.

```
{
  "id": "10",
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "result": [
    {
      "CLIoutput": "Port      Link       Tx Pkt     Tx Byte      Rx Pkt     Rx Byte      Rx Pkt      Rx Pkt      Tx Pkt
     Tx Pkt\n          State       Count       Count       Count       Count       Bcast       Mcast       Bcast       M
cast\n========= ===== =========== =========== =========== =========== =========== =========== =========== ===========\n1
         R               0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0\n========
= ===== =========== =========== =========== =========== =========== =========== =========== ===========\n          > in
Port indicates Port Display Name truncated past 8 characters\n          > in Count indicates value exceeds column width.
 Use 'wide' option or '0' to clear.\n          Link State: A-Active, R-Ready, NP-Port Not Present, L-Loopback\n"
    },
    {
      "show_ports_stats": {
        "dot1dTpPortInDiscards": 0,
        "dot1dTpPortInFrames": 0,
        "dot1dTpPortMaxInfo": 1500,
        "dot1dTpPortOutFrames": 0,
        "linkState": 0,
        "port": 1,
        "portList": 1,
        "portNoSnmp": 1,
        "rxBcast": 0,
        "rxByteCnt": 0,
        "rxMcast": 0,
        "rxPktCnt": 0,
        "txBcast": 0,
        "txByteCnt": 0,
        "txMcast": 0,
        "txPktCnt": 0
      },
      "status": "SUCCESS"
    }
  ]
}
```

When I'm copy/pasting the function into a Powershell window it works as intended:

```
VERBOSE:

   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
Name        MemberType   Definition
----        ----------   ----------
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType     Method       type GetType()
ToString    Method       string ToString()
CLIoutput   NoteProperty string CLIoutput=Port      Link       Tx Pkt     Tx Byte      Rx Pkt     Rx Byte      Rx
Pk...


Port      Link       Tx Pkt     Tx Byte      Rx Pkt     Rx Byte      Rx Pkt      Rx Pkt      Tx Pkt      Tx Pkt
          State       Count       Count       Count       Count       Bcast       Mcast       Bcast       Mcast
========= ===== =========== =========== =========== =========== =========== =========== =========== ===========
```

When I install my module and call the function I get a parsing error:

```
VERBOSE:

   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
Name        MemberType   Definition
----        ----------   ----------
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType     Method       type GetType()
ToString    Method       string ToString()
CLIoutput   NoteProperty System.String CLIoutput=Port      Link       Tx Pkt     Tx Byte      Rx Pkt     Rx Byte
...


Property 'CLIoutput' cannot be found on this object. Make sure that it exists.
At C:\maintenance\PSEXOS\Functions\Invoke-EXOScommand.ps1:114 char:9
+         $clioutput = $responseobj.result.CLIoutput
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], PropertyNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFoundStrict
```

In both cases I have 'CLIoutput' as a NoteProperty, so why isn't it recognized when called from the module? Is this a scope issue? All functions are dotsourced in the .psm1 file.

Also the 2 other functions in the module (Get-Vlans, Get-VlanPortInfo) are designed in a smiliar manner and do work...

Comment: Can you put your code in a simplified way in this question? So people don't have to follow links and when others look for this question there won't be any issues with dead links at some point?

Comment: Sure! The whole project may be a bit much, but those 2 examples may cover it...

Comment: Have you been tinkering with your code / editing the function in the module? Try to eliminate caching problems by removing the module and reimporting it with -Force. I've suffered from this issue in the past. You can confirm that your imported module really is running the latest version of your function by running `Get-Command <commandname> | fl` and it should dump the function contents to the screen. Worth noting for the case that whilst `Get-Vlans`, `Get-VlanPortInfo` do work, they don't contain the problematic $CLIoutput.

Comment: I always copy the module from another folder to ~\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\ to test it and remove it afterwards and open a new PS session. Did what you suggested and got the same error. The main problem I have: It works when copy pasting the functions Send-EXOSrpc and Invoke-Exoscommand into a Powershell window but not when importing the module and calling the Invoke-EXOScommand.

Comment: What version of PowerShell you trying to run this on when you are using a module?

Comment: Tried it in Powershell 5.1 and 3.0 with same results

Comment: Very odd. Although CLIoutput appears visible in Write-Verbose, you could try editing your module to use `$global:response` instead of `$response` After Invoke-EXOScommand completes (and presumably errors) you can at least step through lines 111-114 manually from the command line and inspect what you're really getting back from Send-EXOSrpc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your JSON: `result` property is an array where first object have `CLIoutput` property while second does not. Referencing property, which does not exists, cause error in strict mode (`Set-StrictMode -Version Latest` line in your `PSEXOS.psm1` file). My guess is that you forgot to add this line to your interactive PowerShell session, so it is running not in strict mode, and it just return `$null` for not existing property. It looks like you need to refer to just the first element of `result` array:

```
$clioutput = $responseobj.result[0].CLIoutput
```

Comment: You were right. `$clioutput = $responseobj.result[0].CLIoutput` solved it. Still can't get my head around it. `$responseobj.result | get-member` clearly showed CLIoutput as a NoteProperty. Thank you!

Comment: @joxz But `$responseobj.result[1] | get-member` do not show `CLIoutput` property.